# Spring Boot executable - classnotfound error for main application class

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar

Below is my build.gradle - I have not written any java code over the boiler plate code generated by https://start.spring.io/ - my problem is that after I explode the tar file generated under the distribution folder and run the executable jar (using the script that can be found in the distribution folder), I get a classnotfound exception for the main application class:

*Error: Could not find or load main class com.itreatmd.emr.emrServices.EmrServicesApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.itreatmd.emr.emrServices.EmrServicesApplication*

I looked into the lib folder and I do find my fat jar in it. If I explode the fat jar to search for the main application class, I find it listed as: *BOOT-INF/classes/com/itreatmd/emr/emrServices/EmrServicesApplication.class*.

However, I do not see any spring boot loader classes. in the fat jar.

I suppose I need to modify my build.gradle to correct this issue, but I am unable to find the solution.

```
    plugins {
            id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
            id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
            id 'java'
            id 'distribution'
            id 'application'
    }

    group = 'com.itreatmd.emr'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '11'

    mainClassName = 'com.itreatmd.emr.emrServices.EmrServicesApplication'
    repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
            maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}    
    bootJar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                       'Implementation-Version': version,
                       'Main-Class': 'com.itreatmd.emr.emrServices.EmrServicesApplication'
        }
    }
    test {
            useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to run a jar file from a distribution directly? The distributions created by the application plugin can scripts for Windows and Unix-like platforms that should be used to run the application.

Comment: Yes, I am using that script in distribution to run the application. I am not running the jar directly.

Comment: Andy, would you know as to how the script can load classes from BOOT-INF/classes as essentially it is unable to do that in my case? I have not changed the script from what the build produces in the distribution folder.

Comment: Which distribution are you trying to use? Spring Boot's plugin should [create one named `boot`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#reacting-to-other-plugins-application) that includes the fat jar.

Comment: The contents of the fat jar include:
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
BOOT-INF/
BOOT-INF/classes/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/itreatmd/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/itreatmd/emr/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/itreatmd/emr/emrServices/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/itreatmd/emr/emrServices/EmrServicesApplication.class
BOOT-INF/lib/
...
BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-loader-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar
....

Comment: Andy, I have tried two things:
1. Explode the tar file produced under distribution and then running the script (which is called emrServices) from the bin folder of the exploded tar. This throws the exception: Could not find or load main class com.itreatmd.emr.emrServices.EmrServicesApplication Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.itreatmd.emr.emrServices.EmrServicesApplication
2. Ran the script from bin/bootscripts. This works but if I don't use bootJar but use Jar in my build.gradle. Using bootJar, throws: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problems in that in the recent SprintBoot versions, the build/distribution folder is useless. As I was migrating from an old SpringBoot version to a recent 2.x version, I assumed that I could continue extracting the jars from the tars inside the build/distribution folder and continue (there is some merit to the tars in terms of packaging and distribution). However, the scripts that you find on exploding the tar under distribution is broken. So, simply use the script under bootScripts to continue.